# How do i prevent facebook canvas app from redirecting after user clicks "allow"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I currently have a site and once a user "allows" on Facebook, FB redirects the user back to my website.

This functionality is fine...however, I am trying to get this running in a canvas app.  I would like to ask for permissions embedded in the canvas app and stay in the canvas app after a user clicks "allow" instead of redirecting to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it client-side – call FB.login with the permissions you want granted, and the user will stay on your canvas page.

Comment: Or set the redirect_uri of the auth dialog to be the place you want them to go after login